# want to change input background color if not input not validated using useForm from react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I'm trying to validate a simple form using react-hook-form. I'm handling the validation part fine, the only problem I have at the moment is that I want to change the background color of the input field and at the same time add a little popup text if the field is not validated. I'm able to do the text popup part pretty easily, but can't seem to find a way to change the background color of the input. I was just wondering how it is possible to have a P tag inside the {errors} method and also to set a certain state in the same method.
for example, If I want only the text popup,  I can use the following :

```
<input name="name" {...register("name",{required:true}}/>
{errors.name && <p>Type a name</p>}
```

But how can I handle setting a state inside that method? for example, if I have a state :

```
const [background, setBackground] = useState(false);
```

How should I approach using the setBackground, something similar to this :

```
{errors.name && <p>Type a name</p> && {setBackground(true)}}
```

The following doesn't work, console says I'm rendering too much, but I'm curious If there's a solution similar to that. Would appreciate any advice!
Here's the codesandbox link to better understand what I'm trying to achieve :
https://codesandbox.io/s/aged-lake-ieyctq?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it via using the `useEffect` hook from react that will run your `setBackground` function if an error on the name field was detected:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (errors.name) {
    setBackground(true); // sets background in case there was an error
  } else {
    setBackground(false); // unsets background in case there is no error
  }
}, [errors.name]);
```

See it working on your forked sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-nobel-tpc0ee

Comment: Thank you that's what I was looking for ! an additional question If I may, say I wanted to do the same with the age input, is it best if I declared a new state for it and used a new useEffect method in the same way or is there a less repetitive way to do that?

Comment: That is a very good question! Personally I would not go with any state for this at all, because you already have a state that indicates that there is an error on a specific field. So I would get rid of the background state - and use it in my style definition rightaway. I updated my sandbox to show you: https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-nobel-tpc0ee?file=/src/App.js

Comment: wow that's a perfect way to fix my problem and way easier than what I've been trying to do for hours haha , thanks for taking your time to help, kind lady<3